# Namespace conversion from VS 2017 to VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I have 2 projects created in 2 different versions of Visual Studio: VS 2012 and VS 2017 in C++. I am trying to bring the project from VS 2017 to VS 2012 because it is simpler for me.

On VS 2017 this code is accepted:

```
namespace first::nested {

}
```

So to make it work on VS 2012 I have to do it this way:

```
  namespace first {
      namespace nested {

      }
  }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make this feature work on VS 2012?

Comment: I think it unlikely any tool will already exist. The first code you've showed is C++17 code, brand spanking new in the standard. Older versions of VS are not going to support that in any way.

Comment: so the only way you suggest  would be edit one by one?

Comment: @javascripters: Personally I might write a script to do it for me if there are a hundred instances or more.

Comment: Out of interest, why does your codebase need to be downgraded so it compiles on a what is a pre-C++11 compiler?

Comment: @AndyG could you write me a small sample script to see how it could be done? yeah my knowledge is very old so it more easy for me to edit in C++ 11 or older than newer lol

Comment: @javscripters: That's pretty broad. You could write something in Python that walks your headers and either uses regex to match your nested namespaces, which you then replace, or just do an exact match like `if string == 'namespace first::nested{': string = 'namespace first{ namespace nested{'` It will take a while to get totally right, which is why I said I wouldn't bother with a script unless it was 100 occurrences or more.

Answer (score 2):

[Nested namespace definitions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) is a [C++17 feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B17_features). Visual Studio 2017 supports the C++17 standard while the Visual Studio 2012 does not so there is no way to compile that code with VS 2012. There is no built-in feature to do the conversion / downgrading either. You need to write the parser or use the 3rd party scripts / libraries.

Here is the MSDN documentation for the pre - VS 2017 [support for C++11/14/17 features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: Yes i know that i have readed already the docs! this is why i was hoping someone had already my same issue or maybe had a script or found a 3rd party that helped anything to convert the code easly would be great thanks!